# Does React Router have a beforeEach or guard method?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm coming from Vue Router and I'm trying to figure out how to do the equivilent of this in React Router v6:

`Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {})`

Where `beforeEach` is a guard method that exposes the **old** and **new route** before any navigation takes place. I'm finding React Router docs very confusing, any help or nudges in the right direction would be massively appreciated!

Comment: Nope, nothing built-in and exported. What are you trying to accomplish though?

Comment: I'm just trying to port some route guards from a Vue project. It's a shame it's not built in.

Comment: Well, if you can share the Vue code and explain what it does we may be able to help nudge you in the right direction with an implementation in `react-router`. I'm sure what you are wanting to do in RRD has been done, but maybe with different terminology.